# Parallel.ForEach - handling serial constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

## Overview

Suppose there is a list that can mostly be processed in parallel, but you want to guarantee that no two objects with the same property are processed at the same time.

For example, say each object has a Color attribute and you want to make sure that each color gets processed serially.  Let's assume there will be many, many Colors, so just using a simple partition for each would be inefficient.

So, how can I process a list in parallel where possible, but add a serial constraint, so that no two objects with the same constraint are processed at the same time?

## Research

Apparently Akka.net allows an approach that routes messages to actors using [consistent hashing](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#consistenthashing), which would be one way to make sure objects of the same color are processed serially.  I'm looking for a similar approach without having to use akka, because I don't want to invest in a framework just to get this functionality.

Preferably, I'd like to plug something into a Parallel.ForEach loop, as opposed to using the Task Parallel Library or other lower-level construct.

In pseudo-code, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Widget> list = getWidgets()
var partitionedList = list.PartionBy(elem => elem.Color)
Parallel.ForEach(partitionedList, (widget) => ProcessWidget(widget));
```

If I had to do this from scratch, I'd write a task queue that spins up its own thread pool, and then routes tasks to threads based on a consistent hash.  Each thread would need its own task queue.

Of course that pretty much describes using an Actor system, so if this isn't relatively easy to do, I may just bite the bullet and use Akka.net.

Comment: A simple alternative would be to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store `Mutex` by the attributes that you want to serialize.  While this is easy to implement, it's not very efficient, because we're reducing throughput by blocking threads waiting on the same key, instead of just queuing this to the same thread.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "same constraint?" Do you mean to group items by their properties and then process those groups individually but in parallel within?

Comment: Using the color analogy again, I want to prevent any two threads from processing "Blue" widgets at the same time.  So the constraint is "only one Blue at a time".  

If we were to group by property, so you get a `List<List<Widget>>` grouped by color, and you could parallelize the first list and get about the effect I'm looking for.  But grouping by property requires seeing the whole list at a time, which would prevent working on a stream of events.  

Does this clarify?